# Getting error 'TableData' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new in react js, i have 2 files, `App.js` and `Table.js`, I have included Table.js file in App.js and when i used `<TableData />`, it gives me error, `Line 12:  'TableData' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef`, here i have added my whole code for that, can anyone please help me why it is giving me that error,
App.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Button, Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './Table.js';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.</p>
        <Button variant="primary">Primary</Button>
        <TableData />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Table.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './App.css';


class TableData extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td colSpan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}
export default TableData;
```

Comment: @mouthzipper ,post your comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define TableData when importing.

```
import TableData from './Table.js'
```